# How to get complete original style declaration in a CSS rule from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS declaration that has some non-standard styles in it, "-my-css-style" and when I try to access it with JavaScript it looks like it's been stripped out.

I also have a case where if it's a standard CSS style, "position" but the value is incorrect or misspelled, "absoluute" it is stripped out.

Is there a way to get the original style declaration with the misspelled names, values or non standard styles included?

Example:

```
.myClass {
   position: absoluute;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   -my-style: 100;
}


// JavaScript  
var rule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0];
var keys = rule.cssText; 

// output - two styles missing
// {width:"10px", height:"10px"}

// second example: 
// outputs ".myRule {position:absolute}"
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".MyRule {position:absolute;}")].cssText

// outputs ".myRule {}"
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".MyRule {position:absoluute;}")].cssText
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, but shouldn't custom style properties start with TWO dashes instead of ONE?

Comment: The OP said they just want all styles applied - regardless of validity.

Comment: I think you should do plain text reading of the CSS file in this case .. I don't think there is any need for the browser to keep broken CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif The browser may not need it but I need it. I wouldn't call it broken CSS. It's possible to define your own attributes in an HTML tag and it's possible to define your own styles like browsers use `-webkit`, `-moz`, etc. I will probably have to load in the stylesheet plain text but may face issues with that. In many API's it's responsible to keep the original raw value. I couldn't find it even in the innerHTML or innerText properties.

Comment: I mean good practice not responsible.